# Java loop won't work without println() statement

Tags: java, arrays, loops, infinite, println

I am currently in an intro level programming course for Java. I have a function that is supposed to randomly select two random different pokemon from a list of pokemon. At first, the code didn't work and just repeatedly executed the while loop infinitely. I added in a println statement for debugging and suddenly the function works perfectly.
The function looks like this:

```
public boolean addRandomPokemon()
{
    boolean runCheck = true;
    boolean canUse = true;
    
    while (runCheck)
    {
        int rand = Randomizer.nextInt(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < pokeDeck.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            if(pokeDeck.get(i).getName().equals(POKEMON_NAMES[rand]))
            {
                canUse = false;
            }
        }
        if (canUse)
        {
            Pokemon poke = new Pokemon(POKEMON_NAMES[rand]);
            pokeDeck.add(poke);
            runCheck = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where the integer rand is a random integer (0,3). Can anybody explain why this is happening, and provide a better solution to this problem. Simply explaination is prefered as I am not very experienced at programming.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on SO. You have posted your question in a good way ;)

Comment: From which package are you using the Randomizer?

Comment: Randomizer was a class created as part of the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your pokeDeck has at least one element and if you satisfy the if condition, you put the canUse boolean to false, so you don't enter anymore in the second if

```
    if (canUse)
    {
        Pokemon poke = new Pokemon(POKEMON_NAMES[rand]);
        pokeDeck.add(poke);
        runCheck = false;
    }
```

So your runCheck boolean is always true, so the loop is infinite.

You can fix this behaviour add an else statement as follow:

```
    if (canUse)
    {
        Pokemon poke = new Pokemon(POKEMON_NAMES[rand]);
        pokeDeck.add(poke);
        runCheck = false;
    } else {
        canUse = true;
    }
```

So you have another chance to exit from your loop in the next cicle.

The `println` has no effect in your infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I think System.out.println() has no effect on your problem. This statement is just about to print any value to the console. Also make sure that your pokeDeck does not contain any pokemon in your POKEMON_NAMES array, because it changes the canUse to false then your runCheck will always stay true.

The arranged code:

```
public boolean addRandomPokemon()
{

    boolean runCheck= true;
    boolean status= false; // If we could insert a pokemon it will be true

    ArrayList<Integer> index= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<POKEMON_NAMES.length; i++) index.add(i); //We create the index pool for selection.
    Random rand= new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Current times seed for Random

    while (index.size()>0 && runCheck)
    {
        
        int x= rand.nextInt(index.size());
        int randPoke= index.remove(x);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < pokeDeck.size(); i++)
        {
            if(pokeDeck.get(i).getName().equals(POKEMON_NAMES[randPoke]))
            {
                break;
            }
            
            Pokemon poke = new Pokemon(POKEMON_NAMES[randPoke]);
            pokeDeck.add(poke);
            runCheck = false;
            status= true;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```